# No genes' ID in peak annotations during ChiP-Seq with ChIPpeakAnno R package

Tags: gene-annotation, chip-seq

I am trying to perfom Chip-Seq Analysis which is greatly described in that conversation: [introduction to Chip Seq](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/16701/introduction-to-chip-seq) . The same as autor of mentioned question I am a student of Applied Mathematics and I am doing my best to enter bioinformatics fields.

I am basically at the moment where I would like to annotate peaks with genes' IDs. To do this I am using [ChIPpeakAnno](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/ChIPpeakAnno/inst/doc/ChIPpeakAnno.pdf) `R` package from [Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/ChIPpeakAnno.html). I used below  code to annotate my reads (outputs from `MACS`) with genes' ID's

```
> library(ChIPpeakAnno)
> # data(package = "ChIPpeakAnno")$results[,3]
> macsOutput <- toGRanges(data="example_peaks.bed",
+                                               format = "MACS")

> data(TSS.human.GRCh37)
> macs.anno <- annotatePeakInBatch(macsOutput,
+                                                                AnnotationData=TSS.human.GRCh37,
+                                                                output="overlapping", maxgap=5000L)
> library(org.Hs.eg.db)
> macs.anno <- addGeneIDs(annotatedPeak=macs.anno,
+                                               orgAnn="org.Hs.eg.db",
+                                               IDs2Add="symbol")
> 
> # no annotations for some genes
> as.character(head(as.data.frame(macs.anno)$symbol))
[1] "PTCHD2" "PTCHD2" "PTGER3" NA       "HFM1"   NA
```

**but there occures that there are no genes' annotations for some peaks**. Can anyone tell me why this might happen? And how to avoid this? Does this refer to the `maxgap=5000L` parameter? When creating output from `MACS` I set a parameter for length to be 10 000.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
This how I solved it, I found the solution somewhere here, I don't remember where, and it worked for me.

```
macs.anno <- annotatePeakInBatch(gr_broadPeak, AnnotationData=TSS.human.GRCh38, 
                                     output="both", maxgap=5000L)
 macs.annoL=addGeneIDs(macs.anno,"org.Hs.eg.db",c("symbol", "genename","entrez_id"))
 macs.annoDF=as.data.frame(macs.annoL)
   result=macs.annoDF[which(macs.annoDF$symbol!="NA"),]
```

Comment: I'm on vacations.

Comment: I'll check your solution soon and then, if it will work, I accept it :)